# WP_Query: adding category__in breaks post ordering

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP_Query that is supposed to get all posts that are in a specific category and output them according to the `menu_order`.

My query currently looks like this:

```
$courses_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'course',
    'category__in' => $categories,
    'nopaging' => true,
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
  ));
```

** 'course' is a post type that is hierarchical*

This is what the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'course' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC
```

The ordering works just fine when I remove the `category__in`.
However I need to display all posts according to their menu order. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you use the default categories that in the post type posts or custom taxonomy?

Comment: it's the default 'category' taxonomy, yes

Answer (score 0):

If your `$categories` is not formatted correctly you will get no results for your query. You can use either an array of ints or a single int and they must match the `term_id` of a category.

WP is fussy sometimes about requiring ints as opposed to strings that contain ints. Despite its fussiness, it sometimes returns the wrong thing. Maybe try this before your query:

```
if (!is_array($categories))
    $categories = [$categories];
$categories = array_filter(array_map(function($c) {
    if (is_string($c) && is_numeric($c))
        $c = intval($c);
    return is_int($c) ? $c : null;
}, $categories);
print_r($categories); // Optional, see what it contains before you try to use it.
```

Note that this modifies what `$categories` contains. You may also try to view `$categories` before you run the query to see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the the actual problem. The logic works just fine with selecting the correct posts according to the category. However, the ordering doesn't have any effect and seems to be just ignored when categories are set.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand that was the question. Did you take a look at the SQL that `WP_Query` is running (`$courses_query->request`)?

Comment: Hm, good point – looks okay to me, though:
`SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'course' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC`